# Neo4j-Cypher : Setting display parameters through Cypher.

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-visualization

I need to set specific property of a node as display name for that node.Till now, I am doing the same through the neo4j UI.

[image]

I am selecting the specify property from the list below, where arrow is pointing, as a display on nodes and relationships.

I want to do the same through the **Cypher**.

Ex:   *MATCH (n:SERVER) RETURN n*

To this n, I want to set ip as the display name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cypher is only for reading and writing to a neo4j DB. It provides no support for controlling DB visualization; nor should it, since there is no standardized way to visualize a neo4j DB. I am afraid you will have to continue to use the neo4j browser to control how it displays your data.

Comment: Ok. I am using Java API to run the cypher. Does Java provide any support for visualization.